# Not able to serve my sinatra app with passenger/apache

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, passenger, mod-rails

I have a Sinatra application which I run in dev/stage with Thin, now that is time to move into production I started checking out how to serve in apache with passenger.

I followed mainly

http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/deployment/apache_with_passenger
http://www.rabblemedia.net/blog/installing-rvm-ruby-on-rails-and-passenger-on-centos-6/
http://sergiy.kyrylkov.name/2012/02/26/phusion-passenger-with-apache-on-rhel-6-centos-6-sl-6-with-selinux/

My local box is running fedora 16, apache 2.2, ruby 1.9+

I installed passenger

```
gem install passenger
```

and then

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

pretty much followed the instructions, like adding the passenger module

```
#mod_rails passenger
LoadModule passenger_module /home/orlybg/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/orlybg/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

this is my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/billomatic"
ServerName billomatic
RailsEnv development

<Directory "/var/www/html/billomatic">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel debug
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/billomatic-error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/billomatic-access_log" common
```

And my config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
disable :run, :reload
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bill-o-matic.rb')
run Sinatra::Application
```

When I hit

```
http://billomatic/
```

I get the default apache for fedora page, at first thevhost error log complained about

```
==> billomatic_error.log <==
[Wed Jun 05 12:45:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/billomatic/
```

But then I just gave the billomatic directory 755 permits, and no logs appear anymore there, in the general apache log I see this when I restart:

```
==> error_log <==
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[ 2013-06-05 15:27:50.6784 6952/7f2f3be64740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:440 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nobody', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/orlybg/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '6951', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '48', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '48' }
[ 2013-06-05 15:27:50.6964 6955/7f8f0d25b740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:555 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.6951/generation-0/request
[ 2013-06-05 15:27:50.7037 6952/7f2f3be64740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:564 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-06-05 15:27:50.7071 6960/7f29a108e840 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:271 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.6951/generation-0/logging
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Wed Jun 05 15:27:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.5 PHP/5.4.11 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.3 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.14.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

When I run

```
passenger-memory-stats
```

I get this:

```
--------- Apache processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
7362  1     380.0 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7381  7362  380.1 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7382  7362  380.1 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7383  7362  380.0 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7384  7362  380.0 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7385  7362  380.1 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7386  7362  380.0 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7387  7362  380.0 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
7388  7362  380.1 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
### Processes: 9
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


---- Passenger processes -----
PID   VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------
7363  209.8 MB  ?        PassengerWatchdog
7366  491.1 MB  ?        PassengerHelperAgent
7371  145.5 MB  ?        PassengerLoggingAgent
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)

*** WARNING: Please run this tool as root. Otherwise the private dirty RSS of processes cannot be determined.
```

What's weird is when I execute

```
passenger-status
```

I get: ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.

Also when I try to run either one of the last commands with sudo, the system says the command was not found.

Any clues on what I am missing / doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I also disabled SELinux, and added a tmp/restart.txt in my sinatra project directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/billomatic"` to `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/billomatic/public"`

and `<Directory "/var/www/html/billomatic">` to `<Directory "/var/www/html/billomatic/public">`

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally gave up before this